# Хранение объектов класса внутри программы

Tags: c#

У меня есть проблема.
Я создаю много (более 100 шт) объектов класса и мне их надо как-то хранить для дальнейших манипуляций.

Я пробовал List<T>.

```
public static List<Uroboros> URO = new List<Uroboros>(); // Основное хранилище.
Uroboros kkk = new Uroboros(p1,p2); // Вот объект.
```

Я заношу его в List.

```
URO.Add(new Uroboros(summ, bufer));
```

А потом, когда я сделал это несколько раз и вывожу эти объекты они все равны по значениям последнему объекту.

Это потому что это ***ссылочный*** тип данных?

Как можно организовать хранение кучи объектов? Через ***запись в файл***?
Но ещё надо будет в них выполнять поиск.

Класс Уроборос.

```
    class Uroboros
    {
        public double fSumm { get; set; }
        public int[] fmsv { get; set; }
        public Uroboros(double i1, int[] i2)
        {
            fSumm = i1;
            fmsv = i2;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string s1 = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < fmsv.Length; i++)
            {
                s1 += Convert.ToString(fmsv[i]) + " ";
            }
            s1 = s1 +" "+ fSumm;
            return "\n"+s1;
        }
    }
```

summ, bufer каждый раз уникальные, я их вывожу после генерации в консоль.

Comment: Как вы два раза создаете переменную с одним и тем же названием? А обьекты с одинаковыми значениями потому что у вас обьекты p1 и p2 одинаковые. Обьекты в списке разные по ссылкам

Comment: "А потом, когда я сделал это несколько раз и вывожу эти объекты они все равны по значениям последнему объекту." - описываемое поведение не соответствует приведенному коду.

Comment: @Igor соответствует. Обьекты разные скорее всего, а вот значения p1,p2 повторяются.

Comment: Не знаю, решит ли это вашу проблему, но все же 
`URO.Add(new Uroboros(p1,p2));`  и проверьте, не повторяются ли значения p1/p2

Comment: Покажите код класса `Uroboros`.